# Element of a subgroup generated by two subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and suppose that $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$. I want to know what a typical element in the subgroup $\langle A, B\rangle$ looks like?

Answer (score 4):

Without any assumption on $A$ and $B$, you only can say that such an element is a (finite) product of elements of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: In general, if $x \in \langle A, B\rangle$ then can $x=ababa$ be a possible element, where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$